# GCP limit service account to have conditional access to a single instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-iam

I'd like to set up an instance schedule and apparently this requires the service account to have `compute.instances.start/stop` permissions. The only way to do this is to enable the service account to have admin privileges which adds a whole host of (in my case) unnecessary permissions that come associated with the role.

So I'd like to keep the default role as "Compute Engine Service Agent" and add the admin role with a condition that it only applies to a single VM. So I tried setting the condition as:

```
resource.type == "compute.googleapis.com/Instance"
resource.name == "//compute.googleapis.com/projects/<project>/zones/<zone>/instances/<name>"
```

however I still get an IAM error when I try to apply the schedule. Should this approach work, and what format does 'name' need to be?

Also what are the security risks of setting an unconditional role here? The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/schedule-instance-start-stop#console) basically says "set it" without any further qualification.

EDIT: This condition (above) doesn't seem to scope correctly at all, all VMs show that my service account has the admin role. It's like the `resource.name` is ignored.

I can correctly set this role, scoped to a single VM, using the "Permissions" tab on the Compute Engine Instances page, but still two questions:

1. It seems like the Compute Admin (beta) conditions aren't sufficient, even though they contain instance start/stop. v1 does work though, when set via instance permissions. What's the difference?
2. How can I set the condition correctly as an IAM rule, rather than manually per instance?

Comment: What's your IAM error? Do you have details?

Comment: Same as if the additional permission wasn't there - it says `Compute Engine System service account service-x@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com needs to have [compute.instances.start] permissions applied in order to perform this operation.` But oddly enough if I look at the inherited permissions in the Instances view, I can see that the service account comes up: `Compute Instance Admin (beta) condition:Limit to <my machine> (1) `. I chose 'beta' instead of 'v1' because it seems to have fewer conditions but still has start/stop. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Ah it looks like I can set this within the Compute Engine Instances page? If I add a principal to grant a new permission to a particular VM, it seems to scope it correctly? My initial permission as per my question actually scoped to _all_ VMs but I don't know why? Ok - So my question is semi-solved but I would still like to know how to do this in the IAM panel rather than in the Compute Engine settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach would be to create a [custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) with just the start/stop permissions and then bind that role to the [Compute Engine Service Agent service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#compute_engine_service_account).

To create the custom role:

```
gcloud iam roles create Scheduler --project=$YOUR_PROJECT_ID \
    --title=Scheduler \
    --description="Schedule a VM instance to start/stop" \
    --permissions=compute.instances.start,compute.instances.stop
```

And to bind the custom role to the Compute Engine Service Agent:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID \
    --member="serviceAccount:service-$PROJECT_NUMBER@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
    --role="projects/$PROJECT_ID/roles/Scheduler"
```

This way you avoid the conditional part and just grant the start/stop permissions as I believe was your original intention.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. Do you know how to also scope it to a particular machine? I've added this via the web GUI, but still not via a conditional rule.